# Center divs in center and move new line div to left

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a fixed size divisions in a container. I want them to be centered relatively to the container but if there is division on next line, then it should start it's position from left, see example.

[image]

As you can see, what I have now is displayed at the top of the image, all divisions are aligned in the center of the container, but notice the second line divisions - where they start their position.

The desired effect is displayed in the second example of the image. How can I achieve that with css?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="child">1</div>
 <div class="child">2</div>
 <div class="child">3</div>
 <div class="child">4</div>
 <div class="child">5</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
 text-align:center;
}

.child {
 position:relative;
 display:inline-block;
 width: 500px;
 height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: why cant you just add a class to the div and align them left in css?

Comment: Could you elaborate on how the division gets there?

Comment: not sure about your alignment that they will always looks like 3 image then 2 and then 1. if yes, try to make your layout like this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/dzg46/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add float:left in .child class like this
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YFQvg/2/)**

**CSS:**

```
.child {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;        
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: do you need 3 div's in 1st row, 2 div's in 2nd row, 1 div in 3rd row or just left aligned?